# Essential singularity of the resolvent operator of an unbounded operator

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, unbounded-operators

Is there an unbounded operator with isolated points in the spectrum, not all of which are eigenvalues?
For unbounded operators it is known that isolated spectral points are either poles or essential singularities, and every pole is an eigenvalue. Thus, I need an explicit operator $T$ with $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$ such that $\lambda$ is an essential singularity (and not a pole) of the resolvent operator of $T$. 
Also, it would be better if someone can give such a point $\lambda$ other than infinity. I'm a little new to the $L^2$ spaces, but I'm quite comfortable working with $\ell^2$ space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a bounded quasinilpotent operator $T \in \mathscr{L}(L^2[0,1])$ defined by
$$
                    (Tf)(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt.
$$
This operator has $\sigma(T)=\{0\}$. The resolvent cannot have a pole at $0$ because $T$ is not nilpotent of any order. So the resolvent has an essential singularity. You can solve for the resolvent by solving $(T-\lambda I)f = g$ for $f$:
$$
              (Tf)(x) -\lambda(Tf)'(x) = g \\
                  (Tf)(0) = 0.
$$
To solve this ODE,
$$
                (Tf)'(x) - \frac{1}{\lambda}(Tf) = -\frac{1}{\lambda}g \\
                 \frac{d}{dx}\{e^{-x/\lambda}(Tf)(x)\} = -\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-x/\lambda}g(x) \\
            e^{-x/\lambda}(Tf)(x) = -\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t/\lambda}g(t)dt \\
             (Tf)(x) = -\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{0}^{x}e^{(x-t)/\lambda}g(t)dt
$$
The resolvent has an essential singularity at $0$, as stated:
$$
      R(\lambda) g = -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda^{n+1}}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{(x-t)^{n}}{n!}g(t)dt
$$
**Added for Unbounded Case:** Let $\mathcal{H} = L^2[0,1]\times L^2[0,1]$ and define an operator $L(f,g)=(Tf,T^{-1}g)$ on the domain $\mathcal{D}(L)=L^2[0,1]\times\mathcal{R}(T)$. This is an unbounded operator because $T^{-1}$ is unbounded. And $T^{-1}$ has no spectrum. So $L$ is a closed, densely-defined operator with $\sigma(L)=\{0\}$, and the resolvent of $L$ has an essential singularity at $0$.

Comment: Yes I came across this operator already (thanks for explaining the essential singularity part so well), but I am looking for an unbounded operator. In case of unbounded operators that I know of, it seems like they either have no isolated points in the spectrum or if they do then those isolated points are eigenvalues. I need an unbounded operator with an isolated point in the spectrum which is not an eigenvalue.

Comment: Similar to your example, it is known that the operator  $T(x_n) = (0, x_1, x_2/2, x_3/3, ...)$ on $\ell^2$ space has $\sigma(T) = {0}$ and $\sigma_p(T) = \emptyset$, however this is again bounded. What I need is an unbounded operator for which i was thinking of considering the following:  Let $S(x_n) = (x_1, 2x_2, 3x_3, ...)$ on the domain $D(S) = {(x_n) \in \ell^2 : \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |nx_n|^2 < \infty}$. Then $S$ is unbounded and $\sigma(S) = {1,2,3,..} and $\sigma_p(S) = {1,2,3,...}.

Comment: If now we consider $T \oplus S$ on domain $\ell^2 \oplus D(S)$ in $\ell^2 \oplus \ell^2$, then $T \oplus S$ is unbounded and has 0 as an isolated point of the spectrum which is not an eigenvalue. @TrialAndError i will be obliged if you could suggest whether this works fine?

Comment: @karuna : Oh, very nice! I suggest using $T\oplus T^{-1}$ because $T^{-1}$ is differentiation on absolutely continuous functions for which $f(0)=0$, and this operator has no spectrum! That makes the arguments easier. I'll add that to the solution.

Comment: Ah! yes.. could you also explain how do you get that the range is the absolutely continuous functions with $f(0)=0$? (like i said im not very familiar with $L^2$ space). And in general could you sugeest some good reference for basics and applications of operators on $L^2$ spaces?

Comment: @karuna : The function $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$ vanishes at $0$, and is absolutely continuous because it is the integral of an integrable function.