# Isolated eigenvalue of bounded operator is a pole of the resolvent

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Suppose we have a bounded operator T on a Banach space X, for which it holds that $ 0$ is an isolated point of the spectrum, and
$ \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}({\rm Ker}(T^n))={\rm Ker}(T)$ is one-dimensional. Suppose further that T has no nontrivial, closed, invariant subspaces. Is it true that $ 0  $ must be a pole of the resolvent?

It is quite easy to construct counterexamples when the assumption that $0$ is an eigenvalue is dropped (see for instance [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1765277/essential-singularity-of-the-resolvent-operator-of-an-unbounded-operator) post), but I have been struggling to come up with counterexamples in the case outlined above. Thanks!

Comment: You can make an artificial example: take $L^2\oplus \mathbb{C}$ and $\tilde{T}(f,z)=(Tf,0)$ where $T$ is the example from your post. I guess you should add the assumption that there are no nontrivial closed invariant subspaces.

Comment: Ah yes thats a good point, thank you!